# Mutual Information, is this calculation correct or should I contact the author about fixing it?

Tags: discrete-signals, information-theory

**Background information**

According to Cover's text book on information theory  Mutual Information is calculated as:

$$(1)  I(W;C) = \Sigma_k\Sigma_i P(C_k,W_i)log(\frac{P(C_k,W_i)}{P(C_k)P(W_i)})
$$

Now if we were interested in a single Word W_i we would just calculate this with one sum:

$$(2)   I(W_i;C) = \Sigma_k P(C_k,W_i)log(\frac{P(C_k,W_i)}{P(C_k)P(W_i)})
$$

OR we can rewrite this as

$$ (3)   I(W_i;C) = \Sigma_k P(C_k,W_i)log(\frac{P(W_i|C_k)}{P(W_i)})
$$

because 
$$ (4)  P(W_i|C_k) = \frac{P(W_i,C_k)}{P(C_k)}$$ (unless i am incorrect)

**Question**
While [reading a paper on feature selection using information theory measurements](http://staff.utia.cas.cz/novovic/files/1483.pdf) I came across A segment of the text:

[image]

Should the equation be more like (3), and I should contact the Author, or have I mis-understood/interpreted mutual information?

Comment: I don't see any difference between Prof. Cover's equation $(3)$ and the Author's equation $(2)$ from the paper.

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing wrong with the formulas in the paper.

- MI(S) is the *average* mutual information of set S over all classes c in C. It is NOT a reformulation of the formula for MI(W,C).
- MI(w) is identical to your formula for I(Wi,C)  (except it uses slightly different notation).